# Unable to run TimescaleDB drop_chunks query with C# NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, timescaledb

This is probably a beginner question.

So, I need to purge old data from PostgreSQL programmatically from an already determined time interval (e.g. sensor data older than 3 months). I've managed to successfully run the query in PostgreSQL using pgAdmin but programmatically with NHibernate `IQuery.ExecuteUpdate()` command, it gives me the error message

```
{"could not execute native bulk manipulation query:SELECT drop_chunks('2020-05-15 17:59:30.636'::timestamp, 'attribute_value', 'hm_attr');[SQL: SQL not available]"}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
    at NHibernate.Engine.Query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.ExecuteNativeUpdate(NativeSQLQuerySpecification nativeSQLQuerySpecification, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.ExecuteUpdate()
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.clExecuteQuery.ExecuteSqlCommand(clQueryItem QueryItem, IStatelessSession Session) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\Query\clExecuteQuery.cs:line 184
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.PersistenceManager.ExecuteSQL(String SqlCommand, Object[] ParametersValues) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\PersistenceManager.cs:line 362
```

The InnerException says:

```
    The given key was not present in the dictionary.

   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at NHibernate.Param.NamedParameterSpecification.SetEffectiveType(QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Param.ParametersBackTrackExtensions.ResetEffectiveExpectedType(IEnumerable`1 parameterSpecs, QueryParameters queryParameters)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
```

The other approach I've tried is by using NHibernate `IQuery.List()` which returns

```
Not all named parameters have been set: [':timestamp'] [SELECT drop_chunks('2020-05-15 18:13:08.841'::timestamp, 'attribute_value', 'hm_attr');]
```

with the following stack trace:

```
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractQueryImpl.VerifyParameters(Boolean reserveFirstParameter)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.VerifyParameters()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List()
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.clExecuteQuery.ExecuteQueryInternal(Object[] Parameters, IQuery Query) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\Query\clExecuteQuery.cs:line 476
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.clExecuteQuery.ExecuteQuery(clQueryItem QueryItem, IStatelessSession Session) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\Query\clExecuteQuery.cs:line 247
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.PersistenceManager.SelectSQL(String SQL_Expression, Object[] ParametersValues) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\PersistenceManager.cs:line 674
   at Platform.Server.Kernel.Persistence.PersistenceManager.PurgeTimescaleExpiredChunks(Type EntityType, DateTime PurgeItemsOlderThanThisDate) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\Kernel\PersistenceManager\PersistenceManager.cs:line 1098
   at Platform.Server.SystemBase.TemporalData.AttributeValueHandler.PurgeExpiredItems(String ExpiringProperty, DateTime PurgeItemsOlderThanThisDate) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\SystemBase\TemporalDataManager\AttributeValue\AttributeValueHandler.cs:line 615
   at Platform.Server.SystemBase.Data.clDataManager.ExecutePurge(DateTime PurgeStart) in C:\git\smartmine\Server\Platform\SystemBase\DataManager\clDataManager.cs:line 976
```

TimescaleDB API version: 0.9.2 docs say https://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/api#drop_chunks, which obviously does not cover running things from NHibernate. I'm having a hard time to find NHibernate docs about this query API, because all I've found comes from the "SELECT * FROM" standard usability (like here https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html).

Again, this is probably a beginner question, sorry if I misunderstood something. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was anticipating issues regarding DateTime conversions in the process. Basically, I've faced the TimescaleDB error

```
Cannot call drop_chunks with a date on hypertables with a time type of: timestamp without time zone
```

Because, as the error states, my base hypertable had a date type of actually

```
timestamp without timezone
```

Somehow because of that, after I fixed the issue by casting the date as

```
'2020-05-15 17:59:30.636'::timestamp
```

I've anticipated errors with date conversion and messed the formats by adding .ToString() calls and other overengineering procedures.

Problem was solved by simply passing the crude date as a parameter, so code looks as simple as like

```
SELECT drop_chunks(:p0, :p1, :p2)
```

where :p0 is a DateTime variable, :p1 is the table name and :p2 is the schema name, all case-sensitive, of course.